# Word 2007 remove information from document onscreen

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am working with sensitive information in Word and would like to remove some of the information that breaches privacy legislation.  This information is variable, so I cannot do a simple replace.  I was able to remove the information from the file after saving it as a text file and looping through the file and saving it to a new text file.  The lines where the information occurs always starts with the same information, so that is what I used to trigger the removal of the private info.  Ideally, I would like to be able to do this without saving the file first.  I am a little familiar with VBA in word, but this is beyond my skillset at the moment.

sorry for the ambiguity....the information that needs to be replaced is variable, similar to a Social Security Number, thus a simple search and replace is not possible.  A sample is provided below.  What I am looking for is when the beginning of the line contains ID#, the first 4 characters of the ID number be either x'd out or replaced with a blank.  The last three characters would still be visible for identification purposes.

```
-INQFS-07A-26-------------------------------------DATE:111018-162442-

ID#: XXXXXXX  NAME: XXXXXX, XXXX                     LOCATION : XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX             NUMBER : XXX      PAGE:    1

   --------------C U R R E N T --------------     OPENING BALANCE      --------------S A V I N G S  --------------  C A N T E E N   

     CASH            HOLDS       FREE BALANCE                            CASH            HOLDS       FREE BALANCE                   

     306.52          7.50              299.02      DATE  11/10/11        91.68           0.00              91.68        90.00
```

Comment: In one sentence you say it's variable, in the next you say it occurs in exactly the same place. Which is it?

Comment: Please provide a couple of (sanitised) examples of the text your are trying to find and remove. Otherwise your question is too general to answer.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do what I want it to do.

```
Sub MaskIDNUM()
'
' MaskIDNUM Macro
' Blank out first four characters of the ID# in a printout
'
    Selection.WholeStory
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "ID#: ????"
        .Replacement.Text = "ID#     "
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindAsk
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub
```